# I want to create a menu that shows 1. Client details, 2.Property details and 3. Exit

Tags: c

I want to create a menu that shows:

1. Client details
2. Property details
3. Exit

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
        
void main() {
    char L,F,H;
    float CID,Aoc,Pte,Cost_per_sqft;
    int dicnt,age,ch;
            
    printf("Enter the Client ID\n");
    scanf("%f", &CID);
    printf("Enter the age of client\n");
    scanf("%f", &Aoc);

    if (age >=60) {
        printf("The client is eligible for a discount\n");
    } else if (age<60) {
        printf("The client is not eligible for a discount\n");
    } { 
        printf("Select Porperty type\nF=Flat\nL=Land\nH=House\n");
        scanf("%f", &Pte);
    }

    printf("Please select the menu option\n");
    printf("1.Client ID\n");
    printf("2.Property details\n");
    printf("3.Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &ch);

    switch(ch) {
    case 1:
        printf("Client ID  %f", CID);
        printf("Age of client  %f", Aoc);
    }            
}
```

[image]

It's not letting me enter the option to open a menu, also the age else is doesn't work because `age => 60` is also showing not eligible for discount. The switch case doesn't work either.

Comment: Aside - `age` is uninitialized when first used here:  `if (age >=60)`.  In this statement: `scanf("%f", &Aoc);` did you mean `scanf("%d", &age);`???

Comment: @OP, it may be helpful to provide specific questions even though you are pointing out what is not working. Are you looking for a specific time of solution? Are you just wondering why its not working? etc

It might also help to provide comments in the code showing what your intention/purpose for specific code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

*Problem 1* is that you have defined two variables, `float Aoc` and `int age`, then attempt to use them interchangeably.  Also, the first time `age` is referenced ( here: `if (age >=60)` ) it is uninitialized, which contributes to the problems you have described.

Addressing the following will fix the `if-else` statement for `age`, and will allow the menu to appear...

Since age is typically a non-float value, i.e. 45 or 50, but never expressed as 45.5.

Suggest replacing, `Aoc` everywhere it exists with `age`, (modifying the format specifiers accordingly), and finally, initialize `age` before use.

*Problem 2* is here:

```
...
{ printf("Select Porperty type\nF=Flat\nL=Land\nH=House\n");
      scanf("%f", &Pte);
```

You are prompting user to input a `char` value, then attempt to read it in into a `float` variable `Pte`.  Suggest if desiring to read in as a `char`, use a `" %c"` format specifier, and change `float Pte` to `char Pte`.
(Note space in format specifier, [it is there for this reason](https://www.codesdope.com/discussion/why-are-you-using-a-space-before-c-in-scanf-c-ch/).)

```
{ printf("Select Porperty type\nF=Flat\nL=Land\nH=House\n");
      scanf(" %c", &Pte);//note space in front of %c to consume newline
```

Working code adapted from your original:

```
void main()
{

  char L,F,H;
  float CID,Aoc;/*Pte*/
  float Cost_per_sqft;
  int dicnt,age,ch;
  char Pte;
    
  printf("Enter the Client ID\n");
  scanf("%f", &CID);
  printf("Enter the age of client\n");
  scanf("%d", &age);
  if (age >=60)
  {
      printf("The client is eligible for a discount\n");
  }  
     else if (age<60)
     {
         printf("The client is not eligible for a discount\n");
     }
 { printf("Select Porperty type\nF=Flat\nL=Land\nH=House\n");
  scanf(" %c", &Pte);
}
  printf("Please select the menu option\n");
  printf("1.Client ID\n");
  printf("2.Property details\n");
  printf("3.Exit\n");
  scanf("%d", &ch);
  switch(ch)
  {
    case 1:
        printf("Client ID  %f\n", CID);
        printf("Age of client  %d", age);
        break;
    case 2:
        ;//add content
        break;
    case 3:
        ;//add content
        break;          
    
  }
    
}
```